# Commit to a repository in GitLab not updating issue states in YouTrack

Tags: git, gitlab-ci, youtrack, upsource, jetbrains-hub

I've got UpSource, YouTrack and Hub setup. I have a project called "Overhaul" which has two services UpSource and YouTrack. Both are connected via VCS. UpSource recieves everything that happens within the repository yet when I want to update an issue in YouTrack via a commit message it doesn't update in YouTrack issue tracker, the issue state remains the same.

My commit message would be: `#HAUL-1 Fixed`

YouTrack integration with UpSource is enabled and everything should be working the way I want it to, I've searched everywhere and tried recreating the project over and over and have checked everything time and time again but I cannot figure out what am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the YouTrack installation: Menu > UpSource Integration

Click on your UpSource integration then click enable. This will allow UpSource to push commands to YouTrack.

From: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/youtrack/standalone/7.0/Integration-with-Upsource.html#d67048e120

Answer (score 0):

Try with [fixed #abc] where abc is the issue number

[from the gitlab documentation](https://gitlab.com/help/user/project/issues/automatic_issue_closing.md)

> Awesome commit message
>
> Fix #20, Fixes #21 and Closes group/otherproject#22. This commit is
>   also related to #17 and fixes #18, #19 and
>   https://gitlab.example.com/group/otherproject/issues/23. will
>   close #18, #19, #20, and #21 in the project this commit is pushed to, as well as #22 and #23 in group/otherproject. #17 won't be closed as it
>   does not match the pattern. It works with multi-line commit messages
>   as well as one-liners when used with git commit -m.

Comment: Also not working. Pretty sure I should be doing it the YouTrack way instead of GitLab seeing as I want to update the YouTrack issue states, I do not use GitLab for issue tracking.